# Mysql 5.6 High cpu usage, few connection high queries per second

Tags: mysql, cpu

The mysql server I'm working on is extremely slow.
It is a Mysql 5.6, 15gb ram octacore cpu -innodb_pool_size is 5gb.

Here is what the mysql status command gives ( since the last restart - 6 mns):

---

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          193

Current database:       avl_stats_xxx

Current user:           root@localhost

SSL:                    Not in use

Current pager:          stdout

Using outfile:          ''

Using delimiter:        ;

Server version:         5.6.51 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Protocol version:       10

Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket

Server characterset:    latin1

Db     characterset:    latin1

Client characterset:    utf8

Conn.  characterset:    utf8

UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Uptime:                 6 min 5 sec

Threads: 25  Questions: 8580478  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 439  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 432  Queries per second avg: 23508.158

Here is what the mysql processlist command gives ( since the last restart - 6 mns):

mysql> show processlist;

| Id | User | Host | db | Command | Time | State | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | 195.238.1.1:64962 | avl_real_time_xxx | Sleep | 2 |  | NULL |
| 3 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_yyy | Sleep | 20 |  | NULL |
| 4 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_yyy | Sleep | 20 |  | NULL |
| 9 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_zzz | Sleep | 1 |  | NULL |
| 19 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_aaa | Sleep | 1 |  | NULL |
| 21 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_xxx | Sleep | 5 |  | NULL |
| 22 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_www | Sleep | 1 |  | NULL |
| 43 | qq | 195.238.130.197:62877 | NULL | Sleep | 1 |  | NULL |
| 50 | aa | 195.238.1.1:64963 | avl_real_time_xxx | Sleep | 4 |  | NULL |
| 51 | aa | 195.238.1.1:64964 | avl_staging_xxx | Sleep | 4 |  | NULL |
| 146 | qq | 127.0.0.1:52416 | avl_real_time_aaa | Sleep | 4 |  | NULL |
| 173 | qq | 127.0.0.1:52420 | avl_real_time_bbb | Sleep | 5 |  | NULL |
| 191 | qq | 127.0.0.1:52424 | avl_real_time_xxx | Query | 0 | NULL | SELECT c.cal_id AS cal_ |
| 193 | qq | localhost | avl_stats_xxx | Query | 0 | init | show processlist |
| 196 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_yyy | Sleep | 1 |  | NULL |
| 202 | qq | 195.0.0.1:52430 | avl_real_time_zzz | Sleep | 5 |  | NULL |
| 216 | qq | 195.0.0.1:52434 | avl_real_time_www | Sleep | 12 |  | NULL |
| 217 | aa | 195.238.18.54:49610 | avl_stats_xxx | Sleep | 0 |  | NULL |
| 218 | aa | 195.238.18.57:61926 | avl_wdb_xxx | Sleep | 0 |  | NULL |
| 227 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_aaa | Sleep | 20 |  | NULL |
| 236 | aa | 195.238.18.57:61934 | avl_wdb_xxx | Sleep | 0 |  | NULL |
| 341 | qq | localhost | avl_real_time_vvv | Sleep | 168 |  | NULL |
| 2287 | qq | 195.238.130.197:1608 | avl_staging_vvv | Sleep | 192 |  | NULL |
| 2295 | qq | 195.238.130.197:8939 | avl_staging_vvv | Sleep | 192 |  | NULL |
| 2796 | qq | 195.85.130.197:42997 | NULL | Sleep | 10 |  | NULL |

25 rows in set (0.00 sec)

As asked, this is the global status :

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Aborted_clients | 1 |
| Aborted_connects | 76 |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use | 0 |
| Binlog_cache_use | 0 |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use | 0 |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use | 0 |
| Bytes_received | 195636883 |
| Bytes_sent | 2332543613 |
| Com_admin_commands | 112223 |
| Com_assign_to_keycache | 0 |
| Com_alter_db | 0 |
| Com_alter_db_upgrade | 0 |
| Com_alter_event | 0 |
| Com_alter_function | 0 |
| Com_alter_procedure | 0 |
| Com_alter_server | 0 |
| Com_alter_table | 0 |
| Com_alter_tablespace | 0 |
| Com_alter_user | 0 |
| Com_analyze | 0 |
| Com_begin | 41366 |
| Com_binlog | 0 |
| Com_call_procedure | 22079 |
| Com_change_db | 68452 |
| Com_change_master | 0 |
| Com_check | 0 |
| Com_checksum | 0 |
| Com_commit | 46410 |
| Com_create_db | 0 |
| Com_create_event | 0 |
| Com_create_function | 0 |
| Com_create_index | 0 |
| Com_create_procedure | 0 |
| Com_create_server | 0 |
| Com_create_table | 0 |
| Com_create_trigger | 0 |
| Com_create_udf | 0 |
| Com_create_user | 0 |
| Com_create_view | 0 |
| Com_dealloc_sql | 0 |
| Com_delete | 0 |
| Com_delete_multi | 34 |
| Com_do | 0 |
| Com_drop_db | 0 |
| Com_drop_event | 0 |
| Com_drop_function | 0 |
| Com_drop_index | 0 |
| Com_drop_procedure | 0 |
| Com_drop_server | 0 |
| Com_drop_table | 0 |
| Com_drop_trigger | 0 |
| Com_drop_user | 0 |
| Com_drop_view | 0 |
| Com_empty_query | 0 |
| Com_execute_sql | 0 |
| Com_flush | 0 |
| Com_get_diagnostics | 0 |
| Com_grant | 0 |
| Com_ha_close | 0 |
| Com_ha_open | 0 |
| Com_ha_read | 0 |
| Com_help | 0 |
| Com_insert | 13738 |
| Com_insert_select | 0 |
| Com_install_plugin | 0 |
| Com_kill | 0 |
| Com_load | 0 |
| Com_lock_tables | 0 |
| Com_optimize | 0 |
| Com_preload_keys | 0 |
| Com_prepare_sql | 0 |
| Com_purge | 0 |
| Com_purge_before_date | 0 |
| Com_release_savepoint | 0 |
| Com_rename_table | 0 |
| Com_rename_user | 0 |
| Com_repair | 0 |
| Com_replace | 0 |
| Com_replace_select | 0 |
| Com_reset | 0 |
| Com_resignal | 0 |
| Com_revoke | 0 |
| Com_revoke_all | 0 |
| Com_rollback | 4101 |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint | 0 |
| Com_savepoint | 0 |
| Com_select | 878979 |
| Com_set_option | 28625 |
| Com_signal | 0 |
| Com_show_binlog_events | 0 |
| Com_show_binlogs | 0 |
| Com_show_charsets | 5 |
| Com_show_collations | 29 |
| Com_show_create_db | 0 |
| Com_show_create_event | 0 |
| Com_show_create_func | 0 |
| Com_show_create_proc | 2 |
| Com_show_create_table | 0 |
| Com_show_create_trigger | 0 |
| Com_show_databases | 1 |
| Com_show_engine_logs | 0 |
| Com_show_engine_mutex | 0 |
| Com_show_engine_status | 0 |
| Com_show_events | 0 |
| Com_show_errors | 0 |
| Com_show_fields | 255 |
| Com_show_function_code | 0 |
| Com_show_function_status | 1 |
| Com_show_grants | 0 |
| Com_show_keys | 1 |
| Com_show_master_status | 0 |
| Com_show_open_tables | 0 |
| Com_show_plugins | 2 |
| Com_show_privileges | 0 |
| Com_show_procedure_code | 0 |
| Com_show_procedure_status | 1 |
| Com_show_processlist | 0 |
| Com_show_profile | 0 |
| Com_show_profiles | 0 |
| Com_show_relaylog_events | 0 |
| Com_show_slave_hosts | 0 |
| Com_show_slave_status | 1 |
| Com_show_status | 112 |
| Com_show_storage_engines | 1 |
| Com_show_table_status | 1 |
| Com_show_tables | 1 |
| Com_show_triggers | 0 |
| Com_show_variables | 37 |
| Com_show_warnings | 3 |
| Com_slave_start | 0 |
| Com_slave_stop | 0 |
| Com_stmt_close | 0 |
| Com_stmt_execute | 0 |
| Com_stmt_fetch | 0 |
| Com_stmt_prepare | 0 |
| Com_stmt_reprepare | 0 |
| Com_stmt_reset | 0 |
| Com_stmt_send_long_data | 0 |
| Com_truncate | 0 |
| Com_uninstall_plugin | 0 |
| Com_unlock_tables | 0 |
| Com_update | 597701 |
| Com_update_multi | 1 |
| Com_xa_commit | 0 |
| Com_xa_end | 0 |
| Com_xa_prepare | 0 |
| Com_xa_recover | 0 |
| Com_xa_rollback | 0 |
| Com_xa_start | 0 |
| Compression | OFF |
| Connection_errors_accept | 0 |
| Connection_errors_internal | 0 |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0 |
| Connection_errors_peer_address | 0 |
| Connection_errors_select | 0 |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap | 0 |
| Connections | 29907 |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 2242 |
| Created_tmp_files | 16 |
| Created_tmp_tables | 192507 |
| Delayed_errors | 0 |
| Delayed_insert_threads | 0 |
| Delayed_writes | 0 |
| Flush_commands | 1 |
| Handler_commit | 1499036 |
| Handler_delete | 1 |
| Handler_discover | 0 |
| Handler_external_lock | 3630933 |
| Handler_mrr_init | 0 |
| Handler_prepare | 0 |
| Handler_read_first | 62289 |
| Handler_read_key | 81968963 |
| Handler_read_last | 1309 |
| Handler_read_next | 1173624327 |
| Handler_read_prev | 0 |
| Handler_read_rnd | 1357836 |
| Handler_read_rnd_next | 5858901 |
| Handler_rollback | 4982 |
| Handler_savepoint | 0 |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0 |
| Handler_update | 1828758 |
| Handler_write | 10276501 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status | not started |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data | 112492 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data | 1843068928 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty | 2276 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty | 37289984 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed | 23125 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free | 1182 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc | 14325 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total | 127999 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd | 0 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead | 246948 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted | 93 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests | 1608307941 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads | 187360 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free | 0 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests | 1639558 |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs | 47426 |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs | 0 |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads | 1 |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes | 0 |
| Innodb_data_read | 7196971008 |
| Innodb_data_reads | 439580 |
| Innodb_data_writes | 69234 |
| Innodb_data_written | 861200896 |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written | 23125 |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes | 408 |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins | ON |
| Innodb_log_waits | 0 |
| Innodb_log_write_requests | 162288 |
| Innodb_log_writes | 44940 |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs | 44964 |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs | 0 |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes | 0 |
| Innodb_os_log_written | 103411712 |
| Innodb_page_size | 16384 |
| Innodb_pages_created | 2164 |
| Innodb_pages_read | 439263 |
| Innodb_pages_written | 23125 |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits | 0 |
| Innodb_row_lock_time | 0 |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg | 0 |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max | 0 |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits | 0 |
| Innodb_rows_deleted | 1 |
| Innodb_rows_inserted | 12542 |
| Innodb_rows_read | 1197678754 |
| Innodb_rows_updated | 597637 |
| Innodb_num_open_files | 309 |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes | 0 |
| Innodb_available_undo_logs | 128 |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 534 |
| Key_blocks_unused | 0 |
| Key_blocks_used | 837 |
| Key_read_requests | 3615733 |
| Key_reads | 2002 |
| Key_write_requests | 1006239 |
| Key_writes | 10154 |
| Last_query_cost | 0.000000 |
| Last_query_partial_plans | 0 |
| Max_used_connections | 45 |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows | 0 |
| Open_files | 25 |
| Open_streams | 0 |
| Open_table_definitions | 659 |
| Open_tables | 923 |
| Opened_files | 10248 |
| Opened_table_definitions | 659 |
| Opened_tables | 930 |
| Performance_schema_accounts_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_digest_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_hosts_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_locker_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost | 0 |
| Performance_schema_users_lost | 0 |
| Prepared_stmt_count | 0 |
| Qcache_free_blocks | 0 |
| Qcache_free_memory | 0 |
| Qcache_hits | 0 |
| Qcache_inserts | 0 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes | 0 |
| Qcache_not_cached | 0 |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0 |
| Qcache_total_blocks | 0 |
| Queries | 41651249 |
| Questions | 1647256 |
| Rsa_public_key |  |
| Select_full_join | 5394 |
| Select_full_range_join | 3281 |
| Select_range | 4665 |
| Select_range_check | 0 |
| Select_scan | 115555 |
| Slave_heartbeat_period |  |
| Slave_last_heartbeat |  |
| Slave_open_temp_tables | 0 |
| Slave_received_heartbeats |  |
| Slave_retried_transactions |  |
| Slave_running | OFF |
| Slow_launch_threads | 0 |
| Slow_queries | 3 |
| Sort_merge_passes | 5 |
| Sort_range | 1271 |
| Sort_rows | 572138 |
| Sort_scan | 44741 |
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates | 0 |
| Ssl_accepts | 0 |
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits | 0 |
| Ssl_cipher |  |
| Ssl_cipher_list |  |
| Ssl_client_connects | 0 |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0 |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth | 0 |
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode | 0 |
| Ssl_default_timeout | 0 |
| Ssl_finished_accepts | 0 |
| Ssl_finished_connects | 0 |
| Ssl_server_not_after |  |
| Ssl_server_not_before |  |
| Ssl_session_cache_hits | 0 |
| Ssl_session_cache_misses | 0 |
| Ssl_session_cache_mode | NONE |
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows | 0 |
| Ssl_session_cache_size | 0 |
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts | 0 |
| Ssl_sessions_reused | 0 |
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries | 0 |
| Ssl_verify_depth | 0 |
| Ssl_verify_mode | 0 |
| Ssl_version |  |
| Table_locks_immediate | 1810634 |
| Table_locks_waited | 0 |
| Table_open_cache_hits | 1810503 |
| Table_open_cache_misses | 930 |
| Table_open_cache_overflows | 0 |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used | 0 |
| Tc_log_page_size | 0 |
| Tc_log_page_waits | 0 |
| Threads_cached | 3 |
| Threads_connected | 42 |
| Threads_created | 45 |
| Threads_running | 2 |
| Uptime | 1708 |
| Uptime_since_flush_status | 1708 |

**Mysql status**

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.51, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Connection id | 29852 |
| Current database |  |
| Current user | root@localhost |
| SSL | Not in use |
| Current pager | stdout |
| Using outfile | '' |
| Using delimiter | ; |
| Server version | 5.6.51 MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| Protocol version | 10 |
| Connection | Localhost via UNIX socket |
| Server characterset | latin1 |
| Db characterset | latin1 |
| Client characterset | utf8 |
| Conn. characterset | utf8 |
| UNIX socket | /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock |
| Uptime | 33 min 56 sec |
| Threads | 40 |
| Questions | 50405780 |
| Slow queries | 3 |
| Opens | 949 |
| Flush tables | 1 |
| Open tables | 942 |
| Queries per second avg | 24757.259 |

0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
3 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 26247, id 140672157763328, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 799055, updated 2377875, deleted 773371, read 1738742499
8.07 inserts/s, 348.14 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 647892.02 reads/s

I don't understand how the level of queries per second is so high with so little connection.

Can you help me please ?

Tanks,

Alexandre

I restart the server to boserve reset ratios.

Comment: I am leaving this in a comment since it is not definitive but the only issues I ever had with MySQL 5.6 is lock contention which makes me wonder if the high queries are coming from queries that are waiting for a table to be unlocked. The issues I saw specifically happened in high concurrency scenarios on the same table and the table typically needed to be very large for the locking issue to present. We did experience high CPU when this happened though but that was because our app would retry its query when the query timed out so I am not sure this is directly applicable to your situation.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to look for extreme Global Variables.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated infomations

Comment: We can see your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; report.  We do NOT see SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; at this time.  If you are out of space here, post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the link with us to allow workload analysis.  Your software is POUNDING the server with read requests that are unnecessary.

Comment: Please let the server run for a day before getting GLOBAL STATUS; what you have may be mostly "startup" activity.  Yes, please use some text format, not a HTML table.  And the GLOBAL STATUS is useless without the VARIABLES.  Do you have the slowlog turned on?  With long_query_time = 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

The `status` output shows that there have been 8.5 million queries ('questions' is the same as queries except for those run inside stored procedures) over the past 6 minutes 5 seconds. The arithmetic of 8.5 million queries / 365 seconds results in 23.5k queries per second on average.

You can check the rate of queries or questions:

```
show global status like 'Questions';

<wait 10 seconds>

show global status like 'Questions';
```

You ran SHOW PROCESSLIST and this shows 25 connections at the instant you ran the command. But it doesn't show how many connections and queries were run any other time.

It's pretty common that applications connect briefly, run a few queries (which may be very quick), then disconnect. Most "shared nothing" programming languages act like this, for example, PHP, Ruby, Python. Connections come and go rapidly, so most of them happen in between the times you run SHOW PROCESSLIST.

Another type of application is one that uses a connection pool, which is a fixed number of connections, which are borrowed briefly by different threads in an application. For example this is typical in Java. Again, you may see only 25 connections when you run SHOW PROCESSLIST, but there are many queries executed per second nonetheless.

What's better than just running SHOW PROCESSLIST is to use a real monitoring solution such as [Percona Monitoring and Management](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management), which graphs the rate of queries per second over time.

You said your buffer pool is 5GB, and the data is 15GB. This is a pretty generous ratio (1:3). Often I see applications that can still have a good "hit rate" even if the buffer pool to data is 1:10 or 1:20. It depends on the queries, and how likely they are to query data that is already in the buffer pool.

Querying data from RAM is faster than querying data that is on disk and needs to be loaded into RAM first. If your queries are often waiting for disk, then the CPU is idle, and you get lower CPU utilization. If your queries are mostly reading data in RAM, the CPU doesn't have to wait, so the CPU utilization tends to be higher. Therefore a high CPU load might indicate a good thing, which is the data your queries need are most often in RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Il will try ton install Percona Monitoring. but it will take some times because our IT works on windows. Only servers without X server are on linux. The mysql server is used for real time applications developed in c. Effectively, applicative code open  and close sql connections for each sql modification. I have seen here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-to-set-innodb-buffer-pool-and-why/19181#19181 that for decrease CPU usage, teh solution is to decrease inno_db_pool_size.